# Função java não retorna o valor correto

Tags: java, funções, recursão

Não estou conseguindo obter o valor desejado na função recursiva abaixo. Já testei pôr um System.out.println para monitorar os valores das variáveis cycleLength e n e o resultado foi que para o valor testado(22) a saída seria 16 e n terminaria com o valor 1 realmente. Daí, não consigo entender porque a função fica retornando -1. Para mim o return -1 nunca seria alcançado.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(algorithm(2, 0));

        input.close();
    }

    public static int algorithm(int n, int cycleLength) {
        cycleLength++;
        
        if(n == 1) {
            return cycleLength;
        }
        if(n % 2 == 1) {
            algorithm(3 * n + 1, cycleLength);
        }
        else {
            algorithm(n / 2, cycleLength);
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi a função está sendo chamada recursivamente e o retorno da última chamada está sendo ignorado na chamada anterior (repare que você está chamando a função dentro dela mesma como se ela retornasse `void`, ou seja, não acontece nada com o valor que é retornado, você não está fazendo nada com o valor que volta para ela mesma).

Não sei como o algoritmo deveria ser, mas tem que ser mudado. Provavelmente é só questão de adicionar `return` antes de cada chamada.

Se esse raciocínio estiver certo então ficaria algo assim:

```
public static int algorithm(int n, int cycleLength)
{
    cycleLength++;
    
    if(n == 1) {
        return cycleLength;
    }

    if(n % 2 == 1) {
        return algorithm(3 * n + 1, cycleLength);
    } else {
        return algorithm(n / 2, cycleLength);
    }
}
```